# Rename each selected files differently using php

Tags: php, mysql, loops, rename

My problem is when I select multiple files, it renames all the selected files to the same, but I want to rename each selected files a bit differently and insert into the MySQL and the local folder.

**For example**

First Selected File Would be:

> 1_$date_$rand_.png

Second Selected File Would be:

> 2_$date_$rand_.pnp

And so on...

I also tried with random number but it will rename each selected file to the same as well. I can't figure out how should I do it with loop.

---

My php code to rename a file and upload into database:

```
$rand = rand(0, 99999);
$date = date('Y_m_d-H_i_s-a', time());
$count = 0;
$path = "../../images/"; // Upload directory=
$filename = $date."_".$rand.'.';

foreach ($image as $f => $imgname) {
  $ext = end((explode(".", $imgname)));
 mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO images(name)
 VALUES  ('$filename$ext')");

  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"][$f], "$path/$filename$ext")) {
    $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded files
  }
}
```

Comment: You only define filename one time, move `$filename = $date."_".rand(0, 99999).'.';` inside the loop right before `$ext`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `file_exists()` and a counter

```
$rand = rand(0, 99999);
$date = date('Y_m_d-H_i_s-a', time());
$count = 0;
$fileCounter = 0;
$path = "../../images/"; // Upload directory=
$filename = $date."_".$rand.'.';

foreach ($image as $f => $imgname) {
  $ext = end((explode(".", $imgname)));

    $fileCounter=1;

    $fullFilename = "$filename$fileCounter$ext" ;
    while(file_exists($path . '/'. $fullFilename)){
       $fileCounter ++;
       $filename = "$filename$fileCounter$ext" ;

    }

   mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO images(name) VALUES ('$fullFilename')");

  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"][$f],$path . '/'.$fullFilename )) {
    $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded files
  }

}
```

Comment: That is not working, also there are syntax errors in your code.

Comment: `$filename_$fileCounter_$ext` is throwing an error, I fixed it to `$filename$fileCounter$ext`, but my problem is now it is still the same, I mean it is not renaming each files. Also, the path is inserting into the database before the file name, but  I don't want that.

Comment: I updated, it will add an 1 to all the files, if the file exists it will use 2, etc... and so on.

Comment: Okay, looking good now, but it removed the dot before the extension, so I `"$filename$fileCounter$ext"`, into this `"$filename$fileCounter"."."."$ext"` as now it adding the dot before the extention :) Plus I changed `$fileCounter ++;
       $filename` to `$fileCounter ++;
       $fileCounter `

Comment: Yes, `$fileCounter ++; $filename ` ==> `$fileCounter ++; $fullFilename = `